# A trace identity

Tags: matrices

Let $\Lambda$ is a constant matrix such that its space derivative is zero $\nabla\Lambda=0$, and $U$ is some element of Lie group such that $UU^{-1}=1$. Will it be possible that
$$Tr(\Lambda U\nabla U^{-1})=Tr(\nabla Q)$$

Where $Q=U^{-1}\Lambda U$. The matrix $U$ has space dependence and obviously $\nabla (UU^{-1})=0$.

The reason for my confusion is the following,
$$Tr(\nabla Q) = Tr(\nabla[U^{-1}\Lambda U])=Tr[(\nabla U^{-1})(\Lambda U)+(U^{-1}\Lambda)(\nabla U)]$$
Which is not $Tr(\Lambda U\nabla U^{-1})$. The extra term is not zero, or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, trace(AB)=trace(BA) and you can just rearrange how desired equation.

Comment: @Nurator. I got your point, $Tr(\Lambda U\nabla U^{-1})=Tr[(\nabla U^{-1}][\Lambda U])$. But Is not the derivative  acts on $\Lambda U$ as well?

Comment: Sorry yeah you are right. I have no idea how the derivative interacts with the trace.